# How to use Reflection in order to avoid value boxing?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, blazor, .net-5

I am exploring Blazor's QuickGrid [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/QuickGrid) and found one interesting spot [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/blob/main/src/QuickGrid/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid/Columns/PropertyColumn.cs).

On the 45th line Steve Sanderson left a TODO with a potentially better alternative solution.

I could not resist my curiosity and decided to give it a try and benchmark the solution afterwards. But, unfortunately, my knowledge in Reflection is really poor.

Could anybody help me to understand how the ideas described in the Steve's comment could be achieved?

Thanks

UPD-1: Code snippet of what I have atm

```
    if( typeof(TProp).GetInterface(nameof(IFormattable)) != null ) {

    Type result = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TGridItem), typeof(TProp));
        
    _cellTextFunc = item => FormatValue(compiledPropertyExpression);
}

    // TODO: Consider using reflection to avoid having to box every value just to call IFormattable.ToString
    // For example, define a method "string Format<U>(Func<TGridItem, U> property) where U: IFormattable", and
    // then construct the closed type here with U=TProp when we know TProp implements IFormattable

    private string FormatValue<U>( Func<TGridItem, U> property ) where U : IFormattable
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which bit specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Reflection is slow and I very much doubt you will gain benefit compared to boxing.

Comment: @canton7 I've just tried checking if TProp implements IFormattable and then tried to do something with _cellTextFunc but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Nick Just a curiosity. I've read some articles about that already. But just wanna give it a try. Also, due to Steve's consideration.

Comment: Reflection is perfectly fine when you cache the `TypeInfo` etc, and Steve probably intended to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` which creates a delegate which is pretty fast to call

Comment: @canton7 Updated my thread with the code snippet of what I have atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what Steve meant was to define a method such as:

```
private string? FormatItem<U>(TGridItem item, Func<TGridItem, U> property) where U: IFormattable
{
    return property(item)?.ToString(Format, null);
}
```

(I had to add `item` to make it make sense: perhaps I'm missing something).

We also need to define a spearate version for nullables, since `Nullable<T>` can't satisfy the constraint `IFormattable<T>`, even if `T` does implement `IFormattable<T>`.

```
private string? FormatItemNullable<U>(TGridItem item, Func<TGridItem, U?> property) where U : struct, IFormattable
{
    return property(item)?.ToString(Format, null);
}
```

Then once you know `U`, you can create a delegate which invokes this method:

```
var formatItemMethodInfo = typeof(C<TGridItem, TProp>).GetMethod("FormatItem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!;
var formatItemNullableMethodInfo = typeof(C<TGridItem, TProp>).GetMethod("FormatItemNullable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!;

var formatter = (Func<TGridItem, Func<TGridItem, TProp>, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<TGridItem, Func<TGridItem, TProp>, string>),
    this,
    nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull == null
        ? formatItemMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TProp))
        : formatItemNullableMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull));
```

And finally use this when constructing `_cellTextFunc`:

```
_cellTextFunc = item => formatter(item, compiledPropertyExpression);
```

This has a little bit of upfront cost (creating the delegate), but invoking it is cheap, and means that you don't have to box `item` to `IFormattable` if it's a value type.

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

---

If I were to suggest a better solution, since we're already using compiled expressions with `Property`, I'd extend that and compile the `ToString` call into the expression. Something like:

```
var toStringMethod = typeof(IFormattable).GetMethod("ToString")!;

var propVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(TProp), "prop");

// What to call String(...) on. We need to call prop.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(...)
// if prop is a nullable value type
Expression toStringCallTarget = nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull == null
    ? propVar
    : Expression.Call(
        propVar,
        typeof(TProp).GetMethod("GetValueOrDefault", Type.EmptyTypes)!);

// The ToString(...) call itself
var toStringCall = Expression.Call(
    toStringCallTarget,
    toStringMethod,
    Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this), "Format"),
    Expression.Constant(null, typeof(IFormatProvider)));

// If prop is nullable (class or nullable struct), then we need to do
// prop == null ? null : prop[.GetValueOrDefault()].ToString(...),
// otherwise just call prop.ToString(...)
Expression conditionalCall = default(TProp) == null
    ? Expression.Condition(
        Expression.Equal(propVar, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TProp))),
        Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)),
        toStringCall)
    : toStringCall;

var block = Expression.Block(new[] { propVar },
    Expression.Assign(propVar, Property.Body),
    conditionalCall);

_cellTextFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<TGridItem, string?>>(block, Property.Parameters[0]).Compile();
```

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

---

Just for fun, I put together a benchmark of the original approaches, Steve's proposed approach, and mine and MarcGravell's proposed solutions:

```
namespace MyBenchmarks
{
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class Benchmark
    {
        private readonly GridItem gridItem = new();

        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> originalClass = new Original<GridItem, FormattableClass>() { Property = x => x.Class, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> originalNonNullable = new Original<GridItem, FormattableStruct>() { Property = x => x.NonNullable, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> originalNullable = new Original<GridItem, FormattableStruct?>() { Property = x => x.Nullable, Format = "X" }.Test();

        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> reflectionClass = new ReflectionTest<GridItem, FormattableClass>() { Property = x => x.Class, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> reflectionNonNullable = new ReflectionTest<GridItem, FormattableStruct>() { Property = x => x.NonNullable, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> reflectionNullable = new ReflectionTest<GridItem, FormattableStruct?>() { Property = x => x.Nullable, Format = "X" }.Test();

        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> formatterClass = new FormatterTest<GridItem, FormattableClass>() { Property = x => x.Class, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> formatterNonNullable = new FormatterTest<GridItem, FormattableStruct>() { Property = x => x.NonNullable, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> formatterNullable = new FormatterTest<GridItem, FormattableStruct?>() { Property = x => x.Nullable, Format = "X" }.Test();

        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> compiledExpressionClass = new CompiledExpressionTest<GridItem, FormattableClass>() { Property = x => x.Class, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> compiledExpressionNonNullable = new CompiledExpressionTest<GridItem, FormattableStruct>() { Property = x => x.NonNullable, Format = "X" }.Test();
        private readonly Func<GridItem, string?> compiledExpressionNullable = new CompiledExpressionTest<GridItem, FormattableStruct?>() { Property = x => x.Nullable, Format = "X" }.Test();

        [Benchmark]
        public void OriginalClass() => originalClass(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void OriginalNonNullable() => originalNonNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void OriginalNullable() => originalNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ReflectionClass() => reflectionClass(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ReflectionNonNullable() => reflectionNonNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ReflectionNullable() => reflectionNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void FormatterClass() => formatterClass(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void FormatterNonNullable() => formatterNonNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void FormatterNullable() => formatterNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void CompiledExpressionClass() => compiledExpressionClass(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void CompiledExpressionNonNullable() => compiledExpressionNonNullable(gridItem);

        [Benchmark]
        public void CompiledExpressionNullable() => compiledExpressionNullable(gridItem);
    }

    class Original<TGridItem, TProp>
    {
        public Expression<Func<TGridItem, TProp>> Property { get; set; } = default!;
        public string? Format { get; set; }

        public Func<TGridItem, string?> Test()
        {
            Func<TGridItem, string?> cellTextFunc;

            var compiledPropertyExpression = Property.Compile();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Format))
            {
                // TODO: Consider using reflection to avoid having to box every value just to call IFormattable.ToString
                // For example, define a method "string Format<U>(Func<TGridItem, U> property) where U: IFormattable", and
                // then construct the closed type here with U=TProp when we know TProp implements IFormattable

                // If the type is nullable, we're interested in formatting the underlying type
                var nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TProp));

                if (!typeof(IFormattable).IsAssignableFrom(nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull ?? typeof(TProp)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"A '{nameof(Format)}' parameter was supplied, but the type '{typeof(TProp)}' does not implement '{typeof(IFormattable)}'.");
                }

                cellTextFunc = item => ((IFormattable?)compiledPropertyExpression!(item))?.ToString(Format, null);
            }
            else
            {
                cellTextFunc = item => compiledPropertyExpression!(item)?.ToString();
            }

            return cellTextFunc;
        }

        private string? FormatItem<U>(TGridItem item, Func<TGridItem, U> property) where U : IFormattable
        {
            return property(item)?.ToString(Format, null);
        }
    }

    class ReflectionTest<TGridItem, TProp>
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo formatItemMethodInfo = typeof(ReflectionTest<TGridItem, TProp>).GetMethod("FormatItem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!;
        private static readonly MethodInfo formatItemNullableMethodInfo = typeof(ReflectionTest<TGridItem, TProp>).GetMethod("FormatItemNullable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!;
        public Expression<Func<TGridItem, TProp>> Property { get; set; } = default!;
        public string? Format { get; set; }

        public Func<TGridItem, string?> Test()
        {
            Func<TGridItem, string?> cellTextFunc;

            var compiledPropertyExpression = Property.Compile();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Format))
            {
                // If the type is nullable, we're interested in formatting the underlying type
                var nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TProp));
     
                if (!typeof(IFormattable).IsAssignableFrom(nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull ?? typeof(TProp)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"A '{nameof(Format)}' parameter was supplied, but the type '{typeof(TProp)}' does not implement '{typeof(IFormattable)}'.");
                }

                var formatter = (Func<TGridItem, Func<TGridItem, TProp>, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                    typeof(Func<TGridItem, Func<TGridItem, TProp>, string>),
                    this,
                    nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull == null
                        ? formatItemMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TProp))
                        : formatItemNullableMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull));
                cellTextFunc = item => formatter(item, compiledPropertyExpression);
            }
            else
            {
                cellTextFunc = item => compiledPropertyExpression!(item)?.ToString();
            }

            return cellTextFunc;
        }

        private string? FormatItem<U>(TGridItem item, Func<TGridItem, U> property) where U : IFormattable
        {
            return property(item)?.ToString(Format, null);
        }

        private string? FormatItemNullable<U>(TGridItem item, Func<TGridItem, U?> property) where U : struct, IFormattable
        {
            return property(item)?.ToString(Format, null);
        }
    }

    public interface IFormatter<T>
    {
        string Format(T value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider = null);
    }

    public static class Formatter<T>
    {
        public static IFormatter<T>? Instance { get; }

        static Formatter()
        {
            object? instance = null;
            var underlying = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
            if (typeof(IFormattable).IsAssignableFrom(underlying ?? typeof(T)))
            {
                if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
                {
                    if (underlying is null)
                    {
                        instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SupportedValueTypeFormatter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SupportedNullableFormatter<>).MakeGenericType(underlying));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SupportedRefTypeFormatter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
                }
            }
            Instance = (IFormatter<T>?)instance;
        }
    }

    internal sealed class SupportedNullableFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T?>
        where T : struct, IFormattable
    {
        public string Format(T? value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
            => value is null ? "" : value.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(format, formatProvider);
    }

    internal sealed class SupportedValueTypeFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T>
        where T : struct, IFormattable
    {
        public string Format(T value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
            => value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
    }
    internal sealed class SupportedRefTypeFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T>
        where T : class, IFormattable
    {
        public string Format(T value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
            => value is null ? "" : value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
    }

    class FormatterTest<TGridItem, TProp>
    {
        public Expression<Func<TGridItem, TProp>> Property { get; set; } = default!;
        public string? Format { get; set; }

        public Func<TGridItem, string?> Test()
        {
            Func<TGridItem, string?> cellTextFunc;

            var compiledPropertyExpression = Property.Compile();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Format))
            {
                // If the type is nullable, we're interested in formatting the underlying type
                var nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TProp));

                if (!typeof(IFormattable).IsAssignableFrom(nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull ?? typeof(TProp)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"A '{nameof(Format)}' parameter was supplied, but the type '{typeof(TProp)}' does not implement '{typeof(IFormattable)}'.");
                }

                cellTextFunc = item => Formatter<TProp>.Instance!.Format(compiledPropertyExpression!(item), Format, null);
            }
            else
            {
                cellTextFunc = item => compiledPropertyExpression!(item)?.ToString();
            }

            return cellTextFunc;
        }
    }

    class CompiledExpressionTest<TGridItem, TProp>
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo toStringMethod = typeof(IFormattable).GetMethod("ToString")!;
        public Expression<Func<TGridItem, TProp>> Property { get; set; } = default!;
        public string? Format { get; set; }

        public Func<TGridItem, string?> Test()
        {
            Func<TGridItem, string?> cellTextFunc;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Format))
            {
                // If the type is nullable, we're interested in formatting the underlying type
                var nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TProp));

                if (!typeof(IFormattable).IsAssignableFrom(nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull ?? typeof(TProp)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"A '{nameof(Format)}' parameter was supplied, but the type '{typeof(TProp)}' does not implement '{typeof(IFormattable)}'.");
                }

                var propVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(TProp), "prop");

                Expression toStringCallTarget = nullableUnderlyingTypeOrNull == null
                    ? propVar
                    : Expression.Call(
                        propVar,
                        typeof(TProp).GetMethod("GetValueOrDefault", Type.EmptyTypes)!);

                var toStringCall = Expression.Call(
                    toStringCallTarget,
                    toStringMethod,
                    Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this), "Format"),
                    Expression.Constant(null, typeof(IFormatProvider)));

                Expression conditionalCall = default(TProp) == null
                    ? Expression.Condition(
                        Expression.Equal(propVar, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TProp))),
                        Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)),
                        toStringCall)
                    : toStringCall;

                var block = Expression.Block(new[] { propVar },
                    Expression.Assign(propVar, Property.Body),
                    conditionalCall);

                cellTextFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<TGridItem, string?>>(block, Property.Parameters[0]).Compile();
            }
            else
            {
                cellTextFunc = item => Property.Compile()!(item)?.ToString();
            }

            return cellTextFunc;
        }
    }

    public class GridItem
    {
        public FormattableClass Class { get; } = new FormattableClass();
        public FormattableStruct NonNullable => new FormattableStruct();
        public FormattableStruct? Nullable => new FormattableStruct();
    }

    public class FormattableClass : IFormattable
    {
        public string ToString(string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider) => "";
    }

    public struct FormattableStruct : IFormattable
    {
        public string ToString(string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider) => "";
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmark>();
        }
    }
}
```

With the results:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OriginalClass | 6.111 ns | 0.1206 ns | 0.1128 ns | - | - |
| OriginalNonNullable | 7.568 ns | 0.1793 ns | 0.1677 ns | 0.0038 | 24 B |
| OriginalNullable | 54.260 ns | 1.0880 ns | 1.4893 ns | 0.0038 | 24 B |
| ReflectionClass | 6.750 ns | 0.0630 ns | 0.0590 ns | - |  |
| ReflectionNonNullable | 4.710 ns | 0.0514 ns | 0.0456 ns | - |  |
| ReflectionNullable | 7.374 ns | 0.0819 ns | 0.0726 ns | - |  |
| FormatterClass | 14.054 ns | 0.2079 ns | 0.1843 ns | - | - |
| FormatterNonNullable | 3.521 ns | 0.0907 ns | 0.0849 ns | - | - |
| FormatterNullable | 7.156 ns | 0.0889 ns | 0.0832 ns | - | - |
| CompiledExpressionClass | 2.919 ns | 0.0864 ns | 0.0888 ns | - | - |
| CompiledExpressionNonNullable | 1.815 ns | 0.0405 ns | 0.0379 ns | - | - |
| CompiledExpressionNullable | 1.799 ns | 0.0577 ns | 0.0686 ns | - | - |

As you can see, the only solution which boxes is the original code. The reflection-based approach is faster than Marc's solution for classes, and about the same for structs. However, the expression-based approach is significantly faster than anything.

I've no idea where that extra cost in `FormatterClass` is coming from, but it's repeatable.

I'm deliberately ignoring the cost of constructing the `Func<TGridItem, string>` in this benchmark: the original code is obviously optimised for the case where `Property` rarely changes, and the cost of compiling `Property` is going to dominate anything else most likely.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution! I also got confused by this single Func<> parameter in the method. That’s why I decided to seek for help here. As I said, I am not very familiar with Reflection and its abilities. So, could you please help me compare 2 answers provided here — yours and Marc Gravell’s. I want to understand which one would suit better in terms of this small  project of a grid (collecting opinions and thinking about them).

Comment: I think to fully avoid the box (see `box !!U` in the IL) and correctly support `Nullable<T>` you really need 3 methods here, with constraints etc similar to my 3 concrete implementations.

Comment: This doesn't box -- checked with `MemoryDiagnoser`. The point of this answer isn't to provide the perfect implementation. If I was doing that, I'd go with compiled expressions and combine the cost with the cost of compiling `Property`. This is trying to answer the question "*Could anybody help me to understand how the ideas described in the Steve's comment could be achieved?*"

Comment: @desmondische I've added a section showing that the reflection-based approach is faster or the same as Marc's approach, and added an alternative approach which is faster than both

Comment: @desmondische Edited again to add non-nullable struct support to the reflection-based approach

Comment: great work with the benchmark here; big thumbs up - makes it very easy to compare and contrast

Comment: @MarcGravell and Antony, I was lucky to meet both of you here. Thank you for providing a different approaches and a detailed explanations, and an interesting discussion. I am sure that it will be very helpful for others too. Special thanks to Antony for benchmark tests. I also can't deny the fact that his initial solution was more suitable in the scenario I stated in the question of the thread. Thanks again and have a great day, guys!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a generic interface such as `IFormatter<T>` *without* a generic constraint, and a few private implementations *with* the necessary complaint, and use reflection internally to decide which private implementation to use - a simple version for everything except `Nullable<T>`, and a special-case for that; this is the same approach used by `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

Full example is below, noting that `Formatter<T>.Instance` will be `null` if the `T` doesn't support `IFormattable` (to allow testing, although this could also be handled separately).

The use of generics in the private implementation means we're using "constrained call", so: no boxing there. The special-casing of `Nullable<T>` means we can handle that too, with an additional indirection.

The important thing is that we only do the thinking *once* per type - testing whether the type is nullable, whether it implements `IFormattable`, etc - and this is then cached via a strategy instance. If we do the thinking every time: boxing would probably be cheaper!

Relevant usage for the sample provided (note you could probably simply with a non-generic static class with generic method so you can just do `Formatter.Format(value, format, provider)` and use generic inference from `value` for the rest):

```cs
// L50
if (Formatter<TProp>.Instance is null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"A '{nameof(Format)}' parameter was supplied, but the type '{typeof(TProp)}' does not implement '{typeof(IFormattable)}'.");
}
_cellTextFunc = item => Formatter<TProp>.Instance.Format(compiledPropertyExpression!(item), Format, null);
```

---

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Formatter<int>.Instance!.Format(123, "G"));
Console.WriteLine(Formatter<int?>.Instance!.Format(123, "G"));
Console.WriteLine(Formatter<int?>.Instance!.Format(null, "G"));
Console.WriteLine(Formatter<NotFormattable?>.Instance is null);

struct NotFormattable { }

public interface IFormatter<T>
{
    string Format(T value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider = null);
}

public static class Formatter<T>
{
    public static IFormatter<T>? Instance { get; }

    static Formatter()
    {
        object? instance = null;
        var underlying = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
        if (typeof(IFormattable).IsAssignableFrom(underlying ?? typeof(T)))
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                if (underlying is null)
                {
                    instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SupportedValueTypeFormatter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
                }
                else
                {
                    instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SupportedNullableFormatter<>).MakeGenericType(underlying));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SupportedRefTypeFormatter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
            }
        }
        Instance = (IFormatter<T>?)instance;

    }
}
internal sealed class SupportedNullableFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T?>
    where T : struct, IFormattable
{
    public string Format(T? value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
        => value is null ? "" : value.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(format, formatProvider);
}

internal sealed class SupportedValueTypeFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T>
    where T : struct, IFormattable
{
    public string Format(T value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
        => value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
}
internal sealed class SupportedRefTypeFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T>
    where T : class, IFormattable
{
    public string Format(T value, string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
        => value is null ? "" : value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, Marc! I understand the idea but have a one little question for you. Why this solution is better, or why would you go with a generic interface without a generic constraint?

Comment: @desmondische you need to have the interface *without* the generic constraint, because otherwise the calling code can't use it unless it can prove (to the compiler) that the `TProp` *satisfies* that constraint; our intention here is to *decouple* the checking of the constraint from compile-time to runtime

Comment: Gotcha! I like your solution, it looks pretty elegant. Actually, it is still quite interesting for me what would be Steve’s solution in terms of this grid project. Would it be something similar to @canton7 solution or anything else.. considering that this is the only place where value formatting happens.

Comment: I would be also very grateful if you could help me to compare 2 solutions provided here. I want to understand which one would suit better in terms of this small  project of a grid (collecting opinions and thinking about them).

Comment: @desmondische the other answer does thinking and has multiple allocations per-bind (i.e. per property); this isn't ideal but isn't too terrible; however, it also fails to handle `Nullable<T>` correctly (which is something the original gets for free thanks to the special boxing rules for that scenario), and I *think* (checking now) it actually includes a box in the key method - the one thing we're trying to avoid!

Comment: @desmondische the generated code definitely emits `box !!U` - so now the question is "does the JIT successfully elide that?" - I'm not sure it does in all struct cases - this scenario is very awkward about that. You could get around it by having 3 bespoke target methods much like my 3 concrete strategy implementations, with the matching constraints. On the plus side, it looks "shorter"

Comment: Nice! I am very lucky that it was you who found my question. You gave me some food for thought. Thank you for your time and a detailed answers/explanations. Have a nice day, Marc!

Comment: The code in my answer does not box -- the JIT elides it. Interestingly mine's significantly faster for classes, and yours is slightly faster for structs (although mine doesn't handle nullables, as you noted)

Comment: @canton7 I think the non-elision scenario I'm remembering is `Nullable<T>`; I notice that the benchmark doesn't handle `ReflectionNullable` (presumably because the code doesn't consider it) - so probably that's why we're not seeing the memory-diagnoser output showing boxing: because we're not actually testing that problem scenario

Comment: @MarcGravell Right, the problem scenario can't happen anyway, as `Nullable<T>` can't satisfy `IFormattable<T>`. I've added in a separate path for nullables, as you did.

Comment: @canton7 but it *can* be true that you have a `Nullable<T>` where `T : IFormattable`, which is the scenario we need to handle; the code in the question did that, for example; but yes, it is awkward - hence my comment above that one way to do this efficiently would be to use your code but with 3 methods (the same 3 scenarios as my code, but using your delegate approach)

Comment: @MarcGravell You need two methods (as my earlier edit shows) -- you can handle non-nullable structs and classes with the same method without boxing